# try to connect mysql in vscode with python getting error on windows

Tags: python, mysql

getting error

```
import mysql.connector
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pip to install the module

Type the following into powershell if using IDLE:

> pip install mysql-connector-python

If on pycharm type it into the terminal tab at the bottom.